# exporting to lambda function from a zip does not pick up the sleep module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a nodeJs script and want to put some sleep during the execution.

I have created a local npm package and a project. Project directory are given below.

```
[ec2-user@ip-local lambdaTestFunction]$ ls -ltr
total 888
drwx------. 8 ec2-user ec2-user     98 Nov 13 11:22 node_modules
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    510 Nov 13 13:51 index.js
-rw-------. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 899230 Nov 13 13:51 index.zip
[ec2-user@ip-local lambdaTestFunction]$
```

I have zipped node_modules and index.js and have zipped them as index.zip

node_modules contains the following

```
[ec2-user@ip-local lambdaTestFunction]$ cd node_modules/
[ec2-user@ip-local node_modules]$ ls -ltr
total 12
drwx------. 2 ec2-user ec2-user   73 Nov 13 11:22 deasync-promise
drwx------. 2 ec2-user ec2-user   59 Nov 13 11:22 bindings
drwx------. 2 ec2-user ec2-user   71 Nov 13 11:22 system-sleep
drwx------. 4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Nov 13 11:22 nan
drwx------. 4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Nov 13 11:22 deasync
drwx------. 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Nov 13 11:22 sleep
[ec2-user@ip-local node_modules]$
```

When I execute the script index.js locally, it works well as given below.

```
[ec2-user@ip-local lambdaTestFunction]$ node index.js
starting the function
start before wait
after 5 mins
[ec2-user@ip-local lambdaTestFunction]$
```

But when I export the zip to lambda function, execution fails with the message

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'index/node_modules/sleep'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index/index.js:2:13)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}
```

Contents of index.js is below

```
console.log("starting the function");
var sleep = require('sleep');
console.log("start before wait");
sleep.sleep(5); // 5 seconds
console.log("after 5 mins");


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    //callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
    console.log("start before wait");
    //sleep.sleep(5); // 5 seconds
    //             //setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
    console.log("after 5 mins");
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda after 5 sec');

};
```

I am not sure what am I still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because of the way zipping the files making the problem. Instead of zipping the folder you have to select all files and zip it like below,

Please upload all files and folders including your node_modules folder

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vijay.. But then how about, node_modules, which is missing in your screenshot ?  my zip contans node_modules and index.js ...

Comment: you have to zip node_modules folder as well. I didn't have any external packages installed that's node_modules folder not there